# SQL Query Help Conditional Join

Tags: mysql, sql

Say I have three tables as such:

Group Table

| OGID | OGC | OGCD |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 56 | 300 | TAS |
| 81 | TA | CAL |

Structure Table

| OSID | L1D | L2D |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 44 | 56 | 81 |

Contract

| ContractID |
| --- |
| 44 |

Im giving the ContractID and I want to create a Table that has the follow:

| ContractID | Structure L1D | Structure L2D | Group OGID | Group OGC | Group OGCD | Group OGID | Group OGC | Group OGCD |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 44 | 56 | 81 | 56 | 300 | TAS | 81 | TA | CAL |

What would be the best way to go about this in SQL?
There is also the problem that L2D can be null and anytime I try to make INNER JOIN statements to join the tables, the NULL ones are ignore.

```
SELECT
Contract.ContractID, Structure.L1D, Structure L2D, Group.OGID, Group.OGC, Group.OGID, Group2.OGID, Group2.OGC, Group2.OGID,
FROM
(
SELECT Structure.OSID, Structure.L1d, Group.OGID, Group.OGC, Group.OGCD
FROM Structure
INNER JOIN Group
ON (Structure.L1D = Group.OGID)
) T1
INNER JOIN 
(
SELECT Structure.OSID, Structure.L1D, Group2.OGID, Group2.OGC, Group2.OGCD
FROM Structure
INNER JOIN Group2
ON (Structure.L2D = Group2.OGID)
) T2
ON (T1.OSID = T2.OSID OR T2.OSID = NULL)
```

Comment: Please show that SQL statement you tried. (and the eventual errors it produced).  And sharing some info on what you are actually trying to do might not hurt also... 

Comment: When you have info that is not available, (like `L2D is null`) you should use a `LEFT JOIN`, not an ÌNNER JOIN`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [DBFIDDLE](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=cc25fe8172abb13cad6b3f8b986ca82c)

```
SELECT
  s.OSID,
  s.L1D,
  s.L2D,
  g1.OGID,
  g1.OGC,
  g1.OGCSD,
  g2.OGID,
  g2.OGC,
  g2.OGCSD
  
FROM structure s
LEFT JOIN `group` g1 ON g1.OGID = s.L1D
LEFT JOIN `group` g2 ON g2.OGID = s.L2D
```

The DBFIDDLE also shows what happens when `L2D` has the value `NULL`.

P.S. Generally you should not use, or at least try to avoid, [Reserved Words](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/keywords.html#keywords-8-0-detailed-G) as table names, like `GROUP`.